# Can't receive WM_NCHITTEST over transparent area in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, wndproc

I've a question about transparency in WinForms, but first things first. 
I have just created a super-simple application in WinForms with transparent "body". I've only changed the color of the default Form. Designer code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(538, 312);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion


}
```

So in runtime it's basically just a frame + caption. In Form1.cs the only thing I've added was overridden WndProc function where I did:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const UInt32 WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
        const UInt32 WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            Point screenPoint = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
            Point clientPoint = this.PointToClient(screenPoint);
            string position = "Position: X=" + clientPoint.X.ToString() + "; Y=" + clientPoint.Y.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(position);
            this.Text = position;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

In my mind it should work this way: It simply shows mouse pointer position on the window in window's title. BUT, what is super important - position over transparent area should be shown as well. The "Form" inside my application's window is transparent but it's still a part of my application, right? And here comes my question, because not on every machine it works the same.

There are two cases (the same application!!):
1. I can click on stuff under my application (through this transparent area)
2. The window is just transparent. I can't click on stuff like icons or whatever which are under transparent area.

In first case WM_NCHITTEST message is not send at all (over transparent area) in my WndProc overridden function. Transparent area (so the Form) is literally a hole in my app. In second case Form is transparent but in Window's title I can see my pointer position, so simply WM_NCHITTEST message is being send.

Can anyone explain me where could be a problem? This is the same application. 
I mean, If you want to create an app with a "hole" or with a "glass" or "window"? You have to control it somehow..

Comment: I don't think you should be able to click through a transparent form unless you set the window style to WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.  You shouldn't be getting NCHITTEST messages over the transparent area since that isn't, well, the non-client area.  Did you mean to use NCMOUSEMOVE?  Either way, I can't duplicate your click through issue with the posted code.

Comment: Windows implements the only sane behavior, what is visible to the user's eye is visible to the mouse as well.  No option to override this behavior.  You'd have to do something like overlaying the window with another one whose Opacity property is set to 1.  Still transparent enough, but sufficient to get mouse messages.

Comment: @HansPassant This is a weird issue.  If you pick a color like Fuchsia as the BackColor and TransparencyKey, you're right, it clicks through, but if you pick Salmon, it does not click through (on my Windows 8 desktop).  I've read your other comments regarding the Aero bug; I guess this would fall into that category, at least on Windows 8.